# overdrive voltage margin to enter MOS into subthreshold and saturation region

Tags: mosfet

What is the equation for Vgs value for any MOSFET in such a way that, Below Vgs, Mos is in subthreshold region, Above Vgs, Mos is in saturation region?

Comment: Is this a homework?

Answer (score 1):

Academic: There is probably an equation in your textbook of some sorts.

Practical: There are graphs in your mosfet datasheet ^_^. Most people refer to those. I do not know of a practical equation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question